# Keras Progress Bar generates random batch numbers when using fit_generator

Tags: progress-bar, keras, generator

I'm using an MLP in Keras for binary classification of a set of tabular data. 
Each data point has 66 features and I have millions of data points.
In order to improve memory efficiency when reading my large training set I started to use fit_generator. I put a simple test code here:

```
batch_size = 1
input_dim = 66
train_size = 18240
train_steps_per_epoch = int(train_size/batch_size)
model.fit_generator(generate_data_from_file('train.csv', feature_size=input_dim, batch_size=batch_size),
                            steps_per_epoch=train_steps_per_epoch, nb_epoch=epochs, verbose=1)
```

And here is my generator:

```
def generate_data_from_file(filename, feature_size, batch_size, usecols=None, delimiter=',', skiprows=0, dtype=np.float32):
    while 1:
        batch_counter = 0
        if usecols is None:
            usecols = range(1, feature_size+1)
            x_batch = np.zeros([batch_size, feature_size])
            y_batch = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
        else:
            x_batch = np.zeros([batch_size, len(usecols)])
            y_batch = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
        with open(filename, 'r') as train_file:
            for line in train_file:
                    batch_counter += 1
                    line = line.rstrip().split(delimiter)
                    y = np.array([dtype(line[0])])  # Extracting labels from the first colomn
                    x = [dtype(line[k]) for k in usecols]  # Extracting features
                    x = np.reshape(x, (-1, len(x)))
                    # stacking the data in batches
                    x_batch[batch_counter - 1] = x
                    y_batch[batch_counter - 1] = y
                    # Yield when having one batch ready.
                    if batch_counter == batch_size:
                        batch_counter = 0
                        yield (x_batch, y_batch)
```

In my training data the first colomn are the labels and the rest are the features.
If I have understood fit_generator correctly, I have to stack data in batches and yield them.
The training goes on with no problem, but the progress bar is showing random progress which confuses me. Here I used batch_size = 1 for simplicity. The results are something like this:

```
    1/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 1089s - loss: 0.7444 - binary_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
   38/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 52s - loss: 0.6888 - binary_accuracy: 0.4211      
   72/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 42s - loss: 0.6757 - binary_accuracy: 0.6806
  110/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 36s - loss: 0.6355 - binary_accuracy: 0.7455
  148/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 33s - loss: 0.5971 - binary_accuracy: 0.7500
  185/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 32s - loss: 0.4890 - binary_accuracy: 0.8000
  217/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.4816 - binary_accuracy: 0.8295
  249/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 31s - loss: 0.4513 - binary_accuracy: 0.8474
  285/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.4042 - binary_accuracy: 0.8561
  315/18240 [..............................] - ETA: 30s - loss: 0.3957 - binary_accuracy: 0.8381
```

I don't get why it suddenly jumps from 1/18240 to 38/18240 and then to 72/18240 and so on. When I use bigger batch sizes it has the same behavior.
Is there something wrong with my generator or its just how keras progress bar behaves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may see in [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L294) Keras actually checks how much of time passed since last `progbar` update and it prints it only if it's bigger than a set amount of seconds (which is by default set [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/generic_utils.py#L259)). If your batch computations lasted less than this margin - then `progbar` is not updated and that's why you have different jumps in number of batches.

Comment: Thanks ! That explains why when I use debugger I see them correctly (slower computation ... ).